# pyspark on emr using auto broadcast (even though disabled) and nested join for simple sql query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, broadcast

Running pyspark code on EMR using sqlContext.sql queries.
One of the queries causes a driver.maxResultSize related error to be raised.
Tried using explain on the dataframe resulting from the query to understand why. There I saw that spark is using broadcast with nested join for some reason (without explicit instructions).
I would like to understand:

1) Why does spark use broadcast and nested join to perform this query?

2) Why does the broadcast go through the driver?

3) How do I rewrite my code so that spark will not use broadcast (since the broadcast, or it passing through the driver, seem to be the source of the problem)?

The query causing issues:

```py
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_df_sql_view1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_df_sql_view2")
# Get values from df1 that exist only in df1
df = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT * FROM temp_df_sql_view1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temp_df_sql_view2)""")
df.explain()
```

The error message I got is: `Total size of serialized results of 79 tasks (2.1 GB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (2.0 GB)` even though that driver.maxResultSize used to be 1g but was enlarged in order to fix the error. However, the total size of the results seems to have enlarged with it.

After realising it might be a broadcast issue I disabled autoBroadcast with:

```py
conf = SparkConf()
# This should've disabled auto-broadcast
conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

However using explain() on df still shows the same following plan (which includes broadcast):

`BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildLeft, LeftAnti, ((id#22 = id#19) || isnull((id#22 = id#19)))
:- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode
:  +- *(1) FileScan parquet [id#22,data#23] Batched: false, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://bucket], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<...
+- Generate explode(id#2), false, [id#19]
   +- *(2) Scan ElasticsearchRelation(Map(...,org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@6caa1e7e,None) [id#2] PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:array<string>>
None`

Comment: How are creating conf variable in `conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)` ?

Comment: @moriarty007 defining conf = SparkConf() then using it to create sqlContext

Answer (score 0):

```
df = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT * FROM temp_df_sql_view1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temp_df_sql_view2)""")
df.explain(true)

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Join LeftAnti, ((id#134 = id#139) || isnull((id#134 = id#139)))
:- <left side>
+- <right side>
```

If you see the optimized plan of this query, you will see that Spark have converted a `not in` query to LeftAnti Join.

To convert an optimized logical plan into physical plan, Spark uses some set of `strategy`. For Joins, Spark uses `JoinSelection`.

The way it works is documented here - https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/aefb2e7/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala#L326

```
      //   1. Pick broadcast nested loop join if one side is small enough to broadcast. If only left
      //      side is broadcast-able and it's left join, or only right side is broadcast-able and
      //      it's right join, we skip this rule. If both sides are small, broadcasts the smaller
      //      side for inner and full joins, broadcasts the left side for right join, and broadcasts
      //      right side for left join.
      //   2. Pick cartesian product if join type is inner like.
      //   3. Pick broadcast nested loop join as the final solution. It may OOM but we don't have
      //      other choice. It broadcasts the smaller side for inner and full joins, broadcasts the
      //      left side for right join, and broadcasts right side for left join.
```

As the point 3 states, it fallbacks to broadcast join (even thought broadcast hint is not present and also tableSize > broadcastThreshold).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I still don't understand though:
Why does the broadcast go through the driver (which seems to be causing the driver.maxResuktSize error)?
What can I do to get the wanted result without spark using broadcast (hopefully preventing the error)?